# R plot_ly function plotly package

Tags: r, plot, graph, plotly

```
parameterslist <- cbind(v =c(40, 50, 60))

for (i in 1:nrow(parameterslist)) 
  outlist[[i]] <- ode(func = model, y = yini, times = times, parms = c(parameterslist[i,], parameters))

outlist <- as.data.frame(outlist)

plot_vdisp_3 <- plot_ly(outlist, x = ~times, y = ~power1, name = 'v=30m/s', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~outlist$y1, name = 'v=40m/s', mode = 'lines+markers') %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~outlist$y1.1, name = 'v=50m/s', mode = 'lines+markers') %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~outlist$y1.2, name = 'v=60m/s', mode = 'lines+markers') %>% 
  layout( title = 'Drag force according to different wind speeds', 
          xaxis = list(title = 'Time (hours)'), 
          yaxis = list(title = 'Drag Force')) 
plot_vdisp_3
```

I solved a differential equation and created a dataframe but could not plot properly. Could you please explain what should I change? what does outlist$y1 and outlist$y1.1 mean? I created power1 data frame before. but is it ok? during plotting sometimes I could not see the orange line what is the reason for this?

Thanks.

Here is the part of data frame creation part.

```
times <- seq(from = 0, to = 25, by = 1)

out <- ode(func = model, y = yini, times = times, parms = parameters, method = "rk4")

model_out <- data.frame(times, out) 

power1 <- model_out$y1
force1 <- model_out$y2
temp1 <- model_out$y3
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Eser, the community would be much better positioned to help you if you posted your data, using something such as `dput(outlist)` - without it we are working blind. Also, what would you like your plot to look like?

Comment: sorry. I do not know what is? do you mean that I should write complete code?

Comment: You should type `dput(outlist)` and paste what it gives you. If your dataset if enormous and you only want to provide a subset of `n` observations, you can do `dput(head(outlist, n))` where `n` is the number of observations

Comment: Please edit your question to define what `yini`, `parameters`, and `model` are